# How to Calculate cosine similarity with tf-idf using Lucene and Java

Tags: java, lucene, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I have a query and a set of documents. I need to rank these documents based on the cosine similarity with tf-idf. Can someone please tell me what support I can get from Lucene to compute this ? What parameters I can directly calculate from Lucene (can I get tf, idf directly through some method in lucene?) and how to compute cosine similarity with Lucene (is there any function which directly returns cosine similarity if I pass two vectors of the query and the document ?)

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 4):

Lucene already uses a pimped version of cosine similarity, so if you need the raw CS itself, it's probably doable. I recommend the [official page](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/scoring.html) that discusses Lucene scoring.

If you want to extract that info on your own, this would be an outline of the steps for *tf*:

1. index the corpus;
2. open an `IndexReader`;
3. iterate over all doc ids, 0 to `maxDoc()`;
4. `getTermFreqVector(doc, fieldName);`
5. iterate over the parallel arrays `tfv.getTerms()` and `tfv.getTermFrequencies()`.

As for the *docFreq*, use `IndexReader.terms()` and iterate over this calling `termEnum.docFreq()`.

Comment: I need to calculate tf-idf values and then cosine similarities. I can't find any sample code.

Comment: See [here.](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/DefaultSimilarity.html) This is a Strategy object that you assign to the IndexSearcher so it will use it to get tf and idf, and finally the queryNorm. You will also need to control the index-time field norms by assigning your Similarity to the indexer and implementing computeNorm. Nothing of this is as straightforward as just calculating the cosine similarity, the reason being that this is a highly performant implementation of that calculation, split between index-time and query-time.

Comment: Thanx Marko. But I have one big problem that is how to calculate term frequency and document frequency. Is there any method to get term frequency and document frequency by passing the document corpus ?

Comment: Hey @Marko, can you suggest how to implement this on Solr 8.6? The only difference is I want to achieve this using BERT embeddings. I did some research and some API are missing in the new version of Solr. if you have any example I can refer to then that would be great!