# Cosine Similarity with Lucene only for documents that match

Tags: java, solr, lucene, cosine-similarity

Lucene is a inverse indexing system, as far as I understand, its power lies in the fact that it will compare a query only with documents that at least match a token.

Compared to the naive approach where the query is compared to every document, (even those that don't mention any token that is present in the query) this is a great benefit.

For example if I have the indexed documents:

```
D1: "Hello world said the guy"
D2: "Hello, what a beautiful world"
D3: "random text"
```

**As I see it**, the search for query: "*Hello world*", will only look into the indexed documents D1 and D2 and skips on D3, which saves time.

Is this correct?

Now, I'm trying to calculate the cosine similarity between documents. The input query will be a document and the output should be the cosine score. Which is a number between 0 and 1.

I've already read some approaches that calculate the cosine similarity, but they all do this by comparing the term vector for every document. For example [this](http://qnalist.com/questions/5850232/lucene-cosine-similarity-score-for-more-like-this-query) blog mentioned the following:

> If you really need cosine similarity between documents, you have to
>   enable term vectors for the source fields, and use them to calculate
>   the angle. The problem is that this does not scale well, you would
>   need to **calculate angles with virtually all other documents**.

and this [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10173451/2526441) seems to say the same:

> 3. **iterate over all doc ids**, 0 to maxDoc();

Isn't there a way to only calculate the cosine similarity for documents that match the query and let this return as score for the document?

As a side note,
I did read that the [TFIDFSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_3/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html) comes close, I believe the VSM part is exactly what I need, however this part seems to have disappeared in the Lucene Practical Scoring Function. I'm not sure how I can "transform" this Similarity class to end up with only the pure cosine similarity as result.

So a recap of my question:

1. Is my perception of how the inverse indexes save time correct?
2. Is there way to only calculate cosine similarity for documents that
   actually match one of the tokens, instead of for all the documents?
3. Can I use/transform the `TFIDFSimilarity` class to end up with the
   pure cosine similarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2. It pretty much depends on how you formulate your query. If you formulate a BooleanQuery you can specify which terms of the query must be in the returned document. This is done using [BoolenClause.Occur.MUST](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanClause.Occur.html#MUST).
3. You can write your own similarity by extending TFIDFSimilarity but as you may noticed the Lucene practical scoring is based on cosine similarity. In that formula, queryNorm(q) and norm(t, d) form the denominator of cosine similarity and the summation is the dot product of query vector and document vector.

hint: you can form a sample query and use [explain()](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#explain(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int)) to see the details of scoring.

Comment: Related to (2), does this san that the query will look in each document that is indexed and calculate the score, or will it only consider the documents that actually have that particular term. My question is aiming at the performance of Lucene. Related to (3) I did notice TFIDFSimilarity is based on the cosine sim, but it seems only the queryNorm(q) is part of the cosine sim (https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html) So one has to get rid of the norm and coord() parts?
Additionally (3), How are term vectors related to this scoring?

Comment: I am not sure about the performance but the fact is the returned answers contain the keyword for sure (if you formulate your query correctly), so it is reasonable to just look at the documents that for sure contain the term. queryNorm is the denominator of the cosine similarity, tf*idf is the numerator. Again I highly suggest you use explain(). I had a very similar problem and explain() helped me a lot. Try forming a simple query and calling explain. You will see that coord() has value of 1.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by term vector. In cosine similarity you have a query vector and a document vector. Each of these vectors consists of weights of terms. Weight of term is computed based on tf and idf of the term